# Removing duplicates from a string and printing it same order in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a string :

```
@code='L02.226,L02.239,L02.12,L08.1,L02.232,L02.221,L02.224,L02.229,L02.232,L02.239'
```

I need to check whether it has duplicate values or not.

I used this function to do so and it's working perfectly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DistinctList]
    (@List VARCHAR(MAX),
     @Delim CHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ParsedList TABLE(Item VARCHAR(MAX))
    DECLARE @list1 VARCHAR(MAX), @Pos INT, @rList VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @list = LTRIM(RTRIM(@list)) + @Delim
    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)

    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @list1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@list, @pos - 1)))

        IF @list1 <> ''
            INSERT INTO @ParsedList 
            VALUES (CAST(@list1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)))

        SET @list = SUBSTRING(@list, @pos+1, LEN(@list))
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)
    END

    SELECT @rlist = COALESCE(@rlist+',','') + item
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM @ParsedList) t

    RETURN @rlist
END
```

The result is generated in ascending order, but I need the result as the same order in which I provided the input. Is this possible?

Result currently generated:

```
L02.12,L02.221,L02.224,L02.226,L02.229,L02.232,L02.239,L08.1
```

Desired result:

```
L02.226,L02.239,L02.12,L08.1,L02.232,L02.221,L02.224,L02.229
```

Comment: Do you really have to do this in SQL? It is not designed for such things.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation-2

Comment: Add an int column to your `@ParsedList` table variable, set it to `@pos` (or a counter variable) within the loop then order by it.

Comment: @AlexK. im not much into sql alex can u help me to get my result.

Comment: I might be misreading, but your value of `@Code` doesn't appear to have any duplicates?

Comment: I updated my code @Larnu

Comment: Personally better would be to google `split function`, use that one and it will split your records into rows, after that `select distinct ... order by` will be easy

Comment: Ugh...there are so many things gone wrong here. First that splitter...you should NOT be using a loop for that. Then there is the notion of storing data in a delimited string in the first place. This should be properly normalized data. And if it a parameter you should look into table valued parameters. The real issue here is not in solving the data, but in fixing the process before you get into this situation.

Comment: @SeanLange Totally agree with the use of a `WHILE`. As for storing delimited string in data, yes, it's not ideal. I suppose it depends on where the OP got the intial data from. I'm not a fan of having to, however, put the data back into a delimited string afterwards; i'd rather leave it as a "proper" dataset with multiple rows.

Comment: Also see https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/grouped-concatenation-use-cases/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a `WHILE` loop, which are inherently slow, consider using a Dataset based approach.

I feel like I mention this function a lot, however, Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSpilt8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) in an invaluable piece of work, and works wonders for delimited items.

Then, you can do something alike this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DistinctList_DS_tvf (@Code varchar(8000), @Delim char(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DS.Item ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) AS RN
        FROM DelimitedSplit8K(@Code, @delim) DS)
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8000), @Delim) + Item
                  FROM CTE
                  WHERE RN = 1
                  ORDER BY ItemNumber
                  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Code;
GO
```

Comment: I know some people don't care for Moden's splitter because it is limited to 8,000 characters but it is also just about the only one to include the element position which makes this type of thing possible. Well done.

Comment: Jeff does discuss using a `varchar(MAX)` in the article, @SeanLange . I suppose you *could* have a `MAX` version as well, but it would suffer in performance. Honestly, however, if you have a delimited string that has over 8000/4000 characters in your data, your problem isn't Jeff's solution, it's the data you have. Then your point on the question is very relevant; Fix your data, not your Query.

Comment: NO do not modify his splitter to use MAX. It doesn't suffer from performance, it absolutely ruins it. Aaron Bertrand did that in his article comparing splitters and the performance is horrific. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings (Notice all the comments about it). And Jeff discusses it in his article as a big warning to not modify it. Agree that a delimited string that long is an indication of a much bigger problem.

Comment: @larnu as i told you im not much into sql can you explain the code and what it does?

Comment: The DelimitedSplit8K function splits your string into a table. You can read the article to get a better understanding of that. Then this code takes that table and STUFFs the values back into the delimited string with only the distinct values.

Comment: @ASHWANT In regards to Jeff's function, you'll need to look at his article; he explains everything there. Mine, then takes the dataset (from Jeff's Function) and adds a `ROW_NUMBER` to the data, with a partition on the column `item`, and ordered by `ItemNumber` (which is why Jeff's function is invaluable here). This means that duplicates will receive different numbers. the outer statement then uses `STUFF`, and `FOR XML PATH`, which effectively converts the dataset back into a delimited string. The `WHERE RN = 1` means that only the **1st** value for each distinct value is used.

Comment: To be fair, @SeanLange, Moden's is not the only splitting function that maintains order (I've written several), and to be perfectly honest, the performance issue was still present even without modifying the input type.

Comment: It would be great, @AaronBertrand, if you could update the article Sean linked to then. I'd be most interested in seeing the comparison using Jeff's latest code, using a `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)`.

Comment: @Larnu The SSC folks always skip the follow-up: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up

Comment: And to be clear, my point was not to trash Moden's function (though that's how they all took it and organized a dog-pile), it was to highlight what happens to it when people take the function and change it for their own needs (which is often to support more than 4,000 characters).

Comment: Wasn't suggesting that at all @AaronBertrand . Thanks for sharing the extra link, I appreciate it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand to be fair I didn't say his was the only one with ordinal position, but most of them don't. Sadly the MS one doesn't. I know that some of the folks from SSC took your article the wrong way. I don't just blindly use his even though it was the first non-looping splitter I came across. In fact, I reference your article very frequently. I usually reference Moden's as my preference and yours as another option with excellent alternatives. I consider you a consistent professional and doing something like trashing someone else's work is totally not your style.

Comment: Perhaps an update to the performance tests are in order. Moden no longer uses the 4K as the 8K version is much improved. And to that end I have been asking him for a few years now to update his article with the most recent improvements because they are buried in the follow up discussion to his original article. Both his article and yours are 6 years old now. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, he promised to come back with testing results to prove me wrong, I've been waiting for 6 years and I assume I'll continue to wait. I'm not interested in re-doing all that work every time he changes the function.

Comment: @AaronBertrand LOL. And you shouldn't have to constantly update either. I think we all can agree that if we could just avoid delimited lists none of this would be needed.

Comment: @SeanLange true, that's what the 3rd post tried to put forth: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql And with the new functionality in SQL Server 2016+ this should have been put to bed already

Comment: @AaronBertrand if only it returned the ordinal position...not sure why they skipped that. But yeah, mostly put to bed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution with no loop and no function needed:

```
DECLARE @code VARCHAR(200)='L02.226,L02.239,L02.12,L08.1,L02.232,L02.221,L02.224,L02.229,L02.232,L02.239';


WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @code AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS YourStringAsXml
)
,SortedList AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Inx
          ,x.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Fragment
    FROM Casted 
    CROSS APPLY YourStringAsXml.nodes(N'/x') AS A(x)
)
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + a.Fragment 
    FROM SortedList AS a
    WHERE a.Inx=(SELECT MIN(x.Inx) FROM SortedList AS x WHERE x.Fragment = a.Fragment)
    ORDER BY a.Inx
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

The result

```
L02.226,L02.239,L02.12,L08.1,L02.232,L02.221,L02.224,L02.229
```

The CTE will first tranform a list like `a,b,c` to `<x>a</x><x>b</x><x>c</x>` which allows to address each part separately via XML.
The second CTE retrieves a sorted list, in order to keep the elements in the same order)
It is again a trick using XML how the re-concatenation works. `STUFF()` is just needed to take away the leading comma.

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirement of maintaining the original order.

Comment: @GarethD, why do you think so? The element order is an inherent part of an xml document...

Comment: Correct, but sorting is an inherent part of the distinct operator, which happens after the xml shredding. Compare your output with the desired output and you'll see the first items are different.

Comment: This doesnot meet my requirements @shnugo i need the result in same order as my input.

Comment: @shnugo still the result is unchanged gives same output.

Comment: @ASHWANT Do you speak about the result in my answer? I  forgot to update it, just done so...

Comment: You still need another order by for this to work. In your last query you need to add "order by a.Inx"

Comment: I know using XML is faster than the 8k splitter (at least according to Aaron's testing, I have not done my own), and understand why you would want to try and use it but I am not sure it is so much faster that you can do the split operation twice (two references to `SortedList`) and still get better performance.

Comment: no @shnugo i copied your updated code and executed it. the result is unchanged it gives same old output.

Comment: @ASHWANT I just added the `ORDER BY` as suggested by SeanLange.

Comment: @GarethD It might help to do this in two steps and insert the `SortedList` into a temp table. This would avoid any hassel with CTE's execution order...

Comment: @GarethD Aaron's testing was NOT testing the original 8K splitter. He changed it to receive varchar(max) which if you read the comments and the original Moden article will totally destroy the performance. When using the 8K splitter it is actually quite a bit faster than XML as the number of elements per row increases. CLR is still of course faster.

Comment: Yes, after reading Aaron's article, it wasn't really a fair test; as he had inherently changed Jeff's Splitter. It was almost akin to saying that one car is a lot faster than another, very similarly spec'd car. You find out after, however, that the "faster" car was tested with a light fuel tank and just the driver inside. The other car, however, had a full fuel tank, 4 passengers (plus the driver) inside, a full boot/trunk, and had luggage on the roof rack. Of course the other car was faster! ;)

Comment: @ASHWANT Just because I'm curious. Did you try these approaches against each other? What about performance?

Comment: @Shnugo for what it is worth, the recursive split is around 30 % faster than the XML split in my test

Comment: since i need to complete my task today i dint test the performance @Shnugo